# Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

If POI's are in my database like POINT(-lat long) for locations in my    database then how to pass the database data in mixare with in json structure.

These is the json structure:
http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/DisplayYourOwnData

please suggest me some output with steps as quick as possible?

Comment: so you want to create json request from database?

Comment: yes..but the format should match and app works offline...

Comment: i have used another framework for augmented reality and successfully data are showing mixare isn't very helpfull at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would insist you to use `GSON` in this case and fetch the data from database into HashMap/List or any collection which would be easily converted to `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`,

For eg:-

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("name", "Sriram");
map.put("age", 2);
map.put("dob", new Date(110, 4, 6));
map.put("hobby", "painting");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(map);
System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "dob": "May 6, 2010 12:00:00 AM",
  "age": 2,
  "name": "Sriram",
  "hobby": "painting"
}
```

Checkout [`this`](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/google-gson.html) link for further converstion from collection to JSON and JSON to collections.

Comment: ok telling you after implementing it...Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: Completed Augmented Reality finally with other framework not with mixare thanks for your mutual support bro...

Comment: Hi mainank, I need your support. Can you help me. I am also using Mixare. Did you have better than it.

Comment: Use http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/ with local datasource.java within it